# amCharts 4: How to get series tooltip to show between samples

Tags: tooltip, amcharts4

We've recently upgraded our amCharts library from version 2 to version 4. In version 2, when the user hovered over the chart, the tooltips on the step line series showed up between the samples; whereas, in version 4, they only show up when the cursor is hovering exactly over one of the value points. (See screen shot.) We haven't changed our code in any appreciable way (other than what we had to do to get it to work with version 4), and we'd really like to get that old behaviour back, as it's difficult to get the cursor exactly over a data point in order to see what the value is. (Note: It's often the case in our charts that some series may have more data points than others in a given time/date range, as is the case in the screen shot, where the line series has more data points than the other two series.)

What can we do to get the tooltips on the various series in the chart to show up when the cursor is between data points? (It doesn't necessarily need to follow the cursor exactly as long as it shows up somewhere (e.g., on one or the other data point to either side of the cursor).)

[image: Series tooltip in amCharts 2 vs. amCharts 4]